# How to pass user authentication of a private dataset through SODA API?

Tags: soql, socrata, soda

I need to access a private data set in socrata using SODA API. Suppose below link is the data set

> https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/xxxx-xxx.json

I get the following error when try this.

```
"error" : true,
"message" : "You must be logged in to access this resource"
```

I have valid credentials to access the data set. But how can I pass it through SODA API calls?
I tried the below code but it doesn't work.

> https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/xxxx-xxx.json?$username='myname'&$password='pwd@123'

Comment: What platform are you using to call the api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use either [HTTP Basic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) or [OAuth 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) to authenticate. We have [details on how to do that on the developer portal](http://dev.socrata.com/docs/authentication.html).

Make sure you also provide an application token, as detailed in those docs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass Secret-Token and AppToken with the query string.

#### How to Get secret Token

1. Log in to your portal and select "Create new Application"
2. Enter `https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/xxxx-xxx.json` in the "website" field.
3. Save it.
4. Go to "Manage" and get your AppToken and SecretToken from under "Manage".
5. Now, pass the app token and secret token in the URL according to socrata developer document syntax:

   ```
   https://sandbox.socrata.com/oauth/access_token
   ?client_id=YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN
   &client_secret=YOUR_SECRET_TOKEN
   &grant_type=authorization_code
   &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
   &code=CODE
   ```

I am [also looking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31415047/4839101) for an answer for the same question. After passing the app token I can access public DB but can not access Private DB.